# laravel Echo --> Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined

Tags: laravel, echo, laravel-echo

iv been trying to solve this since morning...i keep get this error..

```
vue.js:1743 TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined
```

i am trying to listen on a channel using this code.i already tried using `Echo.channel` that didn't work so am using the code below which also seem go generate the error i mentioned

```
listen(){
window.Echo.channel('tmp-chanel')
.listen('NewBidMade',(auction_item) => {
console.log('-------wakanda-------');
// this.item = auction_item;
});
},
```

any ideas or possible solutions are welcome

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My problem was that my script tag had the defer attribute. Removing it fixes the problem with the script.

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

To use Laravel Echo, first you have to import it on bootstrap.js

```
resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js
```

Please check if this line of code are uncommented:

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'your-pusher-key'
});
```

Note:
If you use pusher, update the code with your key-s

More info:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting#installing-laravel-echo

Comment: yes .all those where availble. my problem was the defer attribute on my script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Below steps worked for me.

1. I have created file to below path and add this code.

**resources\assets\js\laravel-echo-setup.js**

```js
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
       
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ":" + window.laravel_echo_port
});
```

2. restart system.
3. run this command : laravel-echo-server start